Find point at "t" on a cubic spline with math.net
I am using C# with MathNet to make a 2d cubic spline that I can draw.
I was able to make a spline, but I couldn't figure out if there is a function that takes in a "t" value and spits out a point. I am going to get a bunch of points on the curve then connect them with a line if that helps at all.

If you do it without Math.Net it will probably be easier to see how to work with a cubic spline.

I know how I would do it, but I don't really want to remake it if somebody already made an optimized version that works well.

Does this answer your question? Using MathNet Library to Interpolate along a cubic spline

No it does not, that gives out 1 number, I am looking for a point.

Apparently Math.Net doesn't do what you're looking for. Is Spline Interpolation with C# closer to what you want?

Weird, I would think it would, I might try to find a library that will do it. Thnaks though!

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I think ALGLIB does what I want!
